# R - How to create a function with numeric vectors as arguments

Tags: r, function, vector

1. So I want to create a function that takes a numeric vector as an argument, and takes the max value and the min value and calculates the difference between. I've got to this point so far:

   `v <- as.numeric()
    minmax <- function(v){max(v)-min(v)}
    minmax (v)`

The function works, but I'm sure there is a more convenient way to write this in R

2. I want to add a 2nd argument, called noNAs which defines how the function handles its vectors missing values (NAs) and i would like to have it so when noNAs=TRUE it calculates the difference between max and min without including the NA values. I know there is a way to implement this with na.rm but i have no idea how. I was thinking like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

   `minmax <- function(v,noNAs=T){max(v)-min(v){na.rm=TRUE}}`

Comment: What you want to achive can be done with `diff(range(x))`. For second question: it's really basic stuff that covered in literally any entry level R tutorials, this is wrong site for asking this type of question.

Comment: This should work for the second question `minmax <- function(v,noNAs=T){max(v,na.rm = noNAs)-min(v,na.rm = noNAs)}`

Comment: Well, im sorry that I couldn't find an example for the code i was looking for or nothing alike. I'm sure there is a way to block my future comments if it bothers you so much! 

Niek: Thanks for the help, Apparenlty I was very close to the right answer, but i couldn't just figure out how to impelent the na.rm to the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've very nearly solved your own problem by recognizing that `na.rm` is an argument that controls how missing values are treated.  Now you just need to apply this knowledge to both `min` and `max`.

The benefit of functions is that you can pass your arguments to other functions, just as you have passed `v`. The following will define what you wish:

```
minmax <- function(v, noNA = TRUE){
  max(v, na.rm = noNA) - min(v, na.rm = noNA)
}
```

I would recommend, however, that you use an argument name that is familiar

```
minmax <- function(v, na.rm = TRUE){
  max(v, na.rm = na.rm) - min(v, na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

As pointed out earlier, you may be able to simplify your code slightly by using

```
minmax <- function(v, na.rm = TRUE){
  diff(range(v, na.rm = na.rm))
}
```

Lastly, I would suggest that you don't use `T` in place of `TRUE`.  `T` is a variable that can be reassigned, so it isn't always guaranteed to be `TRUE`.  `TRUE`, on the other hand, is a reserved word, and cannot be reassigned.  Thus, it is a safer logical value to use.

Comment: Thank you! It has been very challening trying to learn to write R code just for my own intrest and to help me do better and automate some things i want to figure out. These kind of tips always help a ton. I've got a basic knownledge of the commands but adding them all into one is the hardest part for me so far. I really appriciate the help!